# Rpy2 import rpy2.robjects as robjects fails

Tags: rpy2

I've installed rpy2 through pip install rpy2. After this in a Jupyter notebook the import works fine:

```
import rpy2
print(rpy2.__version__)
```

which returns `3.1.0`.
However when I type this `import rpy2.robjects as robjects`, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: The system "%s" is not supported.
```

Does someone know where this error comes from and how to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same problem.

I uninstalled the package and reinstalled it with conda (as I use Jupyter notebook through Anaconda):

```
conda install rpy2
```

Doing this it worked just fine.

The version installed was 2.9.4. There may be an issue with the version 3.1.0 I believe.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem. I had previously installed rpy2 2.9.5 with`pip3 install rpy2` and it worked fine. However, today I tried updating it with `pip3 install --upgrade rpy2` and got the following error:

```
Collecting rpy2
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/62/bc/d43df0d9e96a38985a97d1cbdb5722e10cd8fa0da45686972f0b8fd18a67/rpy2-3.2.4.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-irk23ljv/rpy2/setup.py", line 21, in <module>
        from rpy2 import situation
      File "/tmp/pip-build-irk23ljv/rpy2/rpy2/situation.py", line 98
        raise ValueError(f'The system {system} is currently not supported.')
                                                                          ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-irk23ljv/rpy2/
```

I can't just stick to the older version because what I'm actually trying to do is to install another Python package that has rpy2 listed as a dependency. The install fails with the same error message.

Any update on the subject?

### Edit

It looks like this might be a compatibility issue with Python 3.5 -- see https://bitbucket.org/rpy2/rpy2/issues/580/installing-rpy2-on-travis-with-pip. I've just opened an issue here: https://github.com/rpy2/rpy2/issues/356